# How to set Cache-Control header in openwrt uhttpd

Tags: openwrt, uhttpd

I checked the [docs](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/webserver/uhttpd) but couldn't find anything about Cache-Control. I wish to set the following header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0
```

If you know a workaround please let me know. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check here changing the value to 0 to disable or 1 to enable directly in **/etc/config/luci**

```
config internal 'ccache'
    option enable '1'
```

By the way, thats for luci running uhttpd. Any other parameters you need to fiddle with **/etc/config/uhttpd** settings described here https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/webserver/uhttpd